# Hero Section Effect Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a fresh web development student that has started studying this year and I've been interested in getting into more 'interesting' things with regards to CSS etc.

I came across this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8DTzU0Iol8

And when following the code, my images wouldn't load at all. The Jscript animations work, the text/borders are there but the images won't load at all. I have tried multiple 'ways' of inserting the images and nothing wants to come through (with regards to what I have tried.)

I have also ran this through to a few qualified Web developer friends that are actively working in the field and even they couldn't find out the problem.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*background: #000;*/
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .column {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container .column:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.container .column .content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .column .content h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  font-size: 15em;
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.container .column .content .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container .column.active .content .box {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container .column .content .box h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #262626;
}

.container .column .content .box p {
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container .column bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container .column.active .bg.bg1 {
  background: url(bg1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .column.active .bg.bg2 {
  background: url(bg2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .column.active .bg.bg3 {
  background: url(bg3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .column.active .bg.bg4 {
  background: url(bg4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>Vegete the Saiyan Prince</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column active">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>1</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>2</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>3</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>4</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('mouseover', '.container .column', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
      });

      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
  </script>
```

I would upload the images but they're all just some backgrounds for the code anyway. I am sorry for any bad formatting etc. (I am still somewhat fresh to it.)

Thank you in advance <3!

Comment: .bg has no height so you can't see it or it's background image. you have to define a height in your css.

Comment: .container .column bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

But wouldn't this be that?

Comment: you are missing a dot before bg

Comment: I love you so much. Thank you.